# Outputting text on a button to the next activity

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, button, android-activity

I have an app with a number of buttons in the first activity. A finish button has been configured to open a second activity when clicked. I want to be able to view the text on the other buttons in the second activity when clicked. I previously set the onclicklistener on all the buttons in the first activity then called the onclick protocol in the second activity like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    ((Button) v).getText();
}
```

But it doesn't work. I am just wondering if I am doing he right thing by calling the onClick protocol in the second activity and if not how to go about it. I have also tried this code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // 1) Possibly check for instance of first 
    Button b = (Button)v;
    String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Here is the code for the first activity in which all the buttons are present:

```
package com.example.coursework1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button7;
    Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
        button7.setOnClickListener(this);
        //
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void FinishClick()
    {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.coursework1"));

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.button7:
                FinishClick();
                break;
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And here is its .xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginRight="68dp"
        android:text="@string/Panini" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/Tea" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/Sandwich" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:text="@string/Salad" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="@string/Water" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
        android:text="@string/Juice" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="@string/Finish" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code for the second activity is this:

```
package com.example.coursework1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FinishButton extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.finish_button);

    }

public void onClick(View v) {
    ((Button) v).getText();
}


}
```

At the moment button7 is opening the second activity when clicked. I also want to view the text of whichever of the other buttons are clicked in the second activity.

Comment: You Question may look clear, If you provide some more info regrading the code

Answer (score 0):

You can pass these kind of simple string through intent itself

```
Intent newintent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
            newintent.putExtra("type", 1);
            startActivity(resturatntintent);
```

on NextActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ....

        type=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("type", 0);
        ....        
    }
```

edit:

```
 Intent newintent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
                newintent.putExtra("type", 1);
                startActivity(newintent);
```

Comment: Hi, sorry does that say restaurantintent?Does restaurantintent refer to my first activity by any chance? and also does this use the onclick listener on the buttons or is that not needed?

Comment: sorry not restaurantintent its newintent. just pass the string of particular button through intent extras just check for how to add string as extra in intent retrieve the same from it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainActivity`

Declare the **HashSet** globally in your MainActiviy

```
private HashSet<String> hashSet;
```

Add this to your `onCreate`

```
hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
```

This method is the implementation of `View.OnClickListener`  `onClick` method

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        hashSet.add("BUTTON1");
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        hashSet.add("BUTTON2");
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        hashSet.add("BUTTON3");
        break;
    // Do the same for remaining buttons             
    case R.id.button7:
       Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.coursework1");
       intent.putExtra("BUTTONS_DATA", hashSet);
       startActivity(intent);
    break;
}
```

And in your `FinishButton` retrive the `HashSet` and you can get the data which buttons are clicked..through Strings

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        HashSet<String> hashSet = (HashSet<String>) extras
                .get("BUTTONS_DATA");
                    System.out.println("These buttons are clicked in the FirstActvity"); 
        for (String string : hashSet) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error on the hashSet in the MainActivity. And I am also getting an error saying "The method onClick1(View) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method". I renamed the onClick because of the duplicate onClick on button7.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote Android [Vapor](http://vapor-api.com/) which is a small framework that provides abstractions over common APIs to make tasks like this easier. So in your case to construct your intent:

```
$.Intent(this, FinishButton.class).put("buttonText", buttonText);
// NOTE: 'this' is a context handle, so your current activity in this case
```

Then in your `FinishButton` activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
{
   super.onCreate(icicle);
   setContentView(R.layout.finish_button);

   String buttonText = $.Intent(getIntent()).extras().getString("buttonText");

}
```

Also in `VaporBundle` and `VaporIntent` the `.put()` method is overloaded so you can throw any supported type at it :)

Try it out if you like, it's all free and the [source is available too](https://github.com/HodeCode/Vapor-API).

Comment: Hi, sorry can you explain clearly how I would use this? I'm very new to java and android.

Comment: There is a lot of info on the website I linked, but basically it provides APIs that look similar to jQuery, which can be neat and useful layers of abstractions. The code I've used above first shows how to create the Intent (which is used to launch a new activity), and then how to retrieve this raw data in the onCreate method that is called on the newly launched FinishButton activity instance